# I am facing issues while hosting my Flask web application in IIS

Tags: flask, python-3.5, iis-10

I am using Python3.5, IIS10 to deploy flask web application in iis. Can anyone help me to set up iis with python. I saw many examples but i could not able to do so. I guess the error must be related to `web.config`

My error is

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout
```

web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="Bot_Chat.app" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:/inetpub/wwwroot/EtownChatBot/;C:\Program Files\Python35;C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib;C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files\Python35\DLLs;" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="CGI-exe" />
            <add name="FlaskHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe|&quot;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EtownChatBot\wfastcgi.py&quot;" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".py" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".html" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>

            </requestFiltering>
        </security>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add applicationHost.xdt under Your Project directory..

**applicationHost.xdt**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <fastCgi>
      <application xdt:Locator="Match(fullPath)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(activityTimeout)"
            fullPath="C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" activityTimeout="600"/>
    </fastCgi>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Refresh  and Restart your Site.Now it will work..